# object destructuring on class members

Tags: ecmascript-6, destructuring

Using ES6, I have a class in which I'm defining some variables and a function that will take an object and assing my variables to the values of it. This is repetitive, so is there any way I can use destructuring assingment to achieve this?

```
class BasicDataMgmt {

  public id: number;
  public name: string;
  public email: string;
  public phone: string;
  public type: string;

  fetchData(data) {
    this.id = data.id;
    this.name = data.name;
    this.email = data.email;
    this.phone = data.phone;
    this.type = data.type;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be

```
  fetchData(data) {
    Object.assign(this, data);
  }
```

for unsanitized data. Or

```
  fetchData({ id, name, ... }) {
    Object.assign(this, { id, name, ... });
  }
```

for sanitized data.

Using [Lodash `_.pick`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.pick) is beneficial here for doing `Object.assign(this, _.pick(data, ['id', 'name', ...]))`.